# Blender search boxes -using multiple keywords

Tags: graph-editor

I like using the little search box available in the graph editor and dope sheet to filter the view.

Is it possible to use two keywords instead of one?

For example if I want to view both loc and rot values for my objects but nothing else, can I achieve that with the search box? In other words, what is the correct syntax for filtering with multiple keywords?